# Mediawiki - categorize page with changed title - is possible?

Tags: mediawiki

I have pages named by products name. For example : red phone , intel cpu Atom, etc. It´s ok. I have this pages in category products.
But I need add this pages to category product by code too. So I need add to every page some code. For examle e123, e124, b112, etc....

So I need **page Intel Cpu Atom** categorize in **Products** as "Intel Cpu Atom" and in category **Codes** as "e123". Is it possible?

Comment: Afaik you can only change the sort order, but not the title.

Comment: Yeah, this solution I know. But it´s not good for me. I need category with order codes of all saved products. I can make page for product name and code as title and link this in body, but it´s not easy solution. My idea is add some special tag into page with product. For example code tag, or is possible make some fixed redirection? Many thanks for some help P.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think something like this is directly possible, categories don't contain some kind of links to pages with customizable titles, they contain the pages themselves.

I see two ways to work around this:

1. Don't use categories. Just have a normal page *Codes* that will contain a list of all codes, with the right links.
2. Use redirects. For example, the page *Intel Cpu Atom* would be in category *Products* and there would be also a redirect from *e123* to *Intel Cpu Atom*, which would be in category *Codes*.